# Making a table smaller keeping it centered

Tags: tables

I don't get why if I make smaller the table produced by the following code (using \tiny),
the table gets smaller and stays centered,

```
\begin{table}
 \tiny
  \begin{threeparttable}
   
      \caption{Participant Characteristics}
   
      \label{tab:key}
   
         \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangindent=6pt}X r@{\;}l r@{\;}l S[table-format=1.3]@{}}
    
              \toprule
    
              \thead[bl]{Variables} 
       
               & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{More \\experienced \\ investors}} 
       
              &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{Less \\experienced \\ investors}} 
    
              &  {\thead[b]{P-Value\tnote{*}}}\\
     
             \midrule
             Percentage who had
            previously invested in
            the stock market       
                                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{78.50\%} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{36.78\%} & .001  \\
            Years of business work
            experience        
                                &  6.35         & (6.00)             & 1.28         & (2.14)              & .001  \\
            Age     
                                    &  30.46        & (5.83)             &  20.11       & (2.67)              & .001  \\
            Number of courses taken
            that discussed investing
            in mutual funds or the
            stock market        
                                &  1.58         & (1.70)              &  .95        & (1.16)             & .001  \\
            Familiarity with mutual
            funds (1 = not at all
            familiar, 7 = very
            familiar)   
                                & 4.59      & (1.61)              & 3.63        & (4.96)             & .011  \\
            Importance in investing in
            mutual funds or the
            stock market (1 = not
            at all important, 7 =
            very important) 
                                & 5.61      & (1.39)              &  5.24       & (1.31)             & .016  \\
            Peers' views of investing
            in mutual funds or the
            stock market (1 = not
            at all desirable, 7 =
            very desirable)         &  5.14         & (1.26)             &  4.64        & (1.71)              & .009  \\
    
              \bottomrule
        
         \end{tabularx}
    
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \small
            \item[*] All tests are t-tests (one-tailed) except for the percentage investing, which is a chi-square test.
    \end{tablenotes}
    
    
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

while if I do it with the table produced by the following code

```
\begin{table}
\tiny
 
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l l l }

\toprule

    \multirow{3}*{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Unstandardized}               & Standardized       &  & \\
    
                     & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Coefficients}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Coefficients}       & t    & sig\\

    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
                    & B & Std. Error & Beta & & \\
    
    \midrule
        (Constant)      &    30,757     &   6,188   &           &   4,971   &   ,000\\
        Interest Rate       &   ,392        &   ,129        &   ,519        &   3,031   &   ,004\\
        Exchange Rate   &   3,331   &   ,618        &   ,663        &   ,663        &   ,000\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\small
      \item[*] \textit{a. Dependent Variable: Investation}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
```

the table gets smaller, but goes to the left. I would like it to stay centered.

Moreover, I would like to put a title on top of the second table (what is done by \caption for the first one), but using \caption in the second table I get a title that is too close to the table itself.

The code for the first table is by leandriis ([Reproduce a table (using tabular?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606123/reproduce-a-table-using-tabular/606133#606133)).

Any suggestions are welcome.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs} % horizontal lines, such as \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{tabularx} % tabularx environment
\usepackage{siunitx} % S type columns to improve alignment of numbers
\usepackage{threeparttable} % tablenotes environment and \tnote commend
\usepackage{makecell} % \thead command for column headers with manual line breaks

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{table}
 \tiny
  \begin{threeparttable}
   
      \caption{Participant Characteristics}
   
      \label{tab:key}
   
         \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangindent=6pt}X r@{\;}l r@{\;}l S[table-format=1.3]@{}}
    
              \toprule
    
              \thead[bl]{Variables} 
       
               & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{More \\experienced \\ investors}} 
       
              &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{Less \\experienced \\ investors}} 
    
              &  {\thead[b]{P-Value\tnote{*}}}\\
     
             \midrule
             Percentage who had
            previously invested in
            the stock market       
                                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{78.50\%} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{36.78\%} & .001  \\
            Years of business work
            experience        
                                &  6.35         & (6.00)             & 1.28         & (2.14)              & .001  \\
            Age     
                                    &  30.46        & (5.83)             &  20.11       & (2.67)              & .001  \\
            Number of courses taken
            that discussed investing
            in mutual funds or the
            stock market        
                                &  1.58         & (1.70)              &  .95        & (1.16)             & .001  \\
            Familiarity with mutual
            funds (1 = not at all
            familiar, 7 = very
            familiar)   
                                & 4.59      & (1.61)              & 3.63        & (4.96)             & .011  \\
            Importance in investing in
            mutual funds or the
            stock market (1 = not
            at all important, 7 =
            very important) 
                                & 5.61      & (1.39)              &  5.24       & (1.31)             & .016  \\
            Peers' views of investing
            in mutual funds or the
            stock market (1 = not
            at all desirable, 7 =
            very desirable)         &  5.14         & (1.26)             &  4.64        & (1.71)              & .009  \\
    
              \bottomrule
        
         \end{tabularx}
    
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \small
            \item[*] All tests are t-tests (one-tailed) except for the percentage investing, which is a chi-square test.
    \end{tablenotes}
    
    
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


%\begin{tabular}{lccc}
%
%\toprule
%\multirow{2}*{Elemento} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Strati} \\
%\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
%& K & L & M \\
%\midrule
%idrogeno & $1$ & & \\
%litio & $2$ & $1$ & \\
%sodio & $2$ & $8$ & $1$ \\
%\bottomrule
%\end{tabular}



%\begin{tabular}{lcccll}
%
%\toprule
%
%   \multirow{3}*{Model} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Unstandardized Coefficients} & t & sign\\
%   
%   \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
%                   & B & Std. Error & Beta \\
%   
%   \midrule
%       (Constant)      &    30,757     &   6,188   &           &   4,971   &   ,000\\
%       Interest Rate       &   ,392        &   ,129        &   ,519        &   3,031   &   ,004\\
%       Exchange Rate   &   3,331   &   ,618        &   ,663        &   ,663        &   ,000\\
%
%\bottomrule
%\end{tabular}

\begin{table}
\tiny
%\caption{t test results.}
 
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l l l }

\toprule

    \multirow{3}*{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Unstandardized}               & Standardized       &  & \\
    
                     & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Coefficients}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Coefficients}       & t    & sig\\

    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
                    & B & Std. Error & Beta & & \\
    
    \midrule
        (Constant)      &    30,757     &   6,188   &           &   4,971   &   ,000\\
        Interest Rate       &   ,392        &   ,129        &   ,519        &   3,031   &   ,004\\
        Exchange Rate   &   3,331   &   ,618        &   ,663        &   ,663        &   ,000\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\small
      \item[*] \textit{a. Dependent Variable: Investation}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\end{center}

%\begin{center}
%
%\begin{table}
%\tiny
%\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
%\toprule
%Panel A: Percentage of Participants Willing to Invest in Mutual Funds\\
% & Small Set Condition2 & Large Set Condition2 & Difference & Chi-Square & P-Value \\
%\midrule
%forza & $F$ & newton \\
%energia & $E$ & joule \\
%tensione & $V$ & volt \\
%\bottomrule
%\end{tabular}
%
%\end{table}
%
%\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: Why do you want to use such a small font size for your tables? This will make it extremely hard to read their contents. Both tables should fit into the available space (for example inside a regulat `article` class) perfectly fine.

Comment: I provided the MWE.

Comment: Remove the `center` environments around the `table` environments.

Comment: Done. Was it useless?

Comment: Not just useless but wrong. It can lead to undesired side effects such as the one described here: [Tables and sections get misplaced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15511/134144)

Comment: Your second table is missing the `threeparttable` environment, you used in the first one. Thus, adding `\tiny
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{t test results.}` between `\begin{table}` and `\begin{tabular}`, as well as adding `\ed{threeparttable}` between `\end{tablenotes}` and `\end{table}` should result in the expected output.

Comment: Thank you leandriis! I have another question regarding another table, I'll make a new post.